# Why is the reported size of this directory in Windows (7) so inaccurate?

Tags: windows

What you see below is two directories.  The first, on the left, is the the original directory I was zipping up with 7-zip.  It is reported as 4.26GB.  On the right, we have how large the zip file came out to be after zipping it.

[image]

Why is there such a disparity between the two?  There's a big difference between 4.26 GB and 91 GB ...

Comment: One explanation: You don't have list access to all files/folders, so you can't count their size...

Comment: @billc.cn That sounds like another possibility...thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably got the picture on the left with lower privileges (non-Admin), while archived with Admin privileges.

Other, less likely explanations include:

- `Users` were changed between the time left and right pictures were taken
- Left picture was taken before size counting was complete
- `Users` may have an item linked/bound to some external storage location (some directory outside the `Users`, or maybe even WebDAV location), which was not available when the left picture was taken.

Comment: Users were changed between the time left and the right pictures were taken, it isn't that because it's an old windows installation backup from when I re-installed Windows.

Well I'm sure it wasn't taken before the size counting was complete, because I asked this question 3 hours ago, and the same dialog is still opened and it still reads 4.25 GB.  So we can rule that one out.

Now that last one I could believe.  Now might there be some way to use robocopy to disconnect the linked/bound items?

Comment: This appears to hold some promise: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-7-infinite-loop-while-using-robocopy/20f32f0c-4cb9-4125-923d-6a57e4d27232

Comment: Yup that did the trick.  Used robocopy to copy the files without the links.