# Why would WinExplorer show inaccurate directory size and # of files?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, ownership, directory-listing

I'm running Win 10 and recovering from a system crash. I'm copying music directories from my backup external drive. But when I try to confirm that everything has been done correctly, I see discrepancies in number of files and size of directory.

that mystifies me. I have lots of directories and subdirectories,  but I'm seeing wide disrepancies. After copying directories from my hard drive, I'm seeing that the C drive has 9 gigs (in compared to 120 gigs on my external hard drive).

If it happened once, I can blame it on sluggish Win application. But I'm seeing it several times. Curiously, if I enter into the subdirectory, select all files and right-click to see properties, the quantitative information tends to be correct (although not always!).

When I run winmerge, often it doesn't catch many diffs in directory contents. Once, it caught nothing.

Another question suggests that the problem may have to do with file ownership. [Why is the reported size of this directory in Windows (7) so inaccurate?](https://superuser.com/questions/352120/why-is-the-reported-size-of-this-directory-in-windows-7-so-inaccurate) That is possible; these files were copied from one machine to another. But every time I copy something from an external hard drive, do I need to run a command to take ownership before I run copy?

Comment: The strange thing though is that I can see all the files on the external HD before they are copied, but not on the actual Windows PC. That does not make sense.

Comment: @rjnagle - Have you taken ownership of the files as previously suggested?

Comment: UPDATE: I changed ownership on the files residing on the external HD. I copied them onto my local system, but only about there are major discrepancies -- which I'll mention in the original question.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. When I ran FOLDER COMPARE (Trial Version), I see that the directory in question has identical files. ONly File Explorer shows discrepancies